# Get all jobs in Quartz.NET 2.0

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, quartz.net

I've setup my AdoJobStore on the server and all my jobs are running perfectly. Now I am writing a remote client to manage all my jobs.

Scheduling new jobs is straightforward enough, but I can't seem to retrieve a list of existing jobs in version 2.0. All the resources I found did something like the following.

```
var groups = sched.JobGroupNames;
for (int i = 0; i < groups.Length; i++)
{
    string[] names = sched.GetJobNames(groups[i]);
    for (int j = 0; j < names.Length; j++)
    {
        var currentJob = sched.GetJobDetail(names[j], groups[i]);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that GetJobNames has been removed, and looking at the source code, has been moved to the base class JobStoreSupport, which JobStoreCMS inherits from. The method has however been marked as protected, so it is inaccessible from the outside.

How would one go about retrieving a job list in 2.0?

Comment: Hey do u have any examples on editing schedules? Im new to this and having a nightmare! please help

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use fetch a list of executing jobs:

```
var executingJobs = sched.GetCurrentlyExecutingJobs();
foreach (var job in executingJobs)
{
    // Console.WriteLine(job.JobDetail.Key);
}
```

or fetch all the info about scheduled jobs (sample console application):

```
private static void GetAllJobs(IScheduler scheduler)
{
    IList<string> jobGroups = scheduler.GetJobGroupNames();
    // IList<string> triggerGroups = scheduler.GetTriggerGroupNames();

    foreach (string group in jobGroups)
    {
        var groupMatcher = GroupMatcher<JobKey>.GroupContains(group);
        var jobKeys = scheduler.GetJobKeys(groupMatcher);
        foreach (var jobKey in jobKeys)
        {
            var detail = scheduler.GetJobDetail(jobKey);
            var triggers = scheduler.GetTriggersOfJob(jobKey);
            foreach (ITrigger trigger in triggers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(group);
                Console.WriteLine(jobKey.Name);
                Console.WriteLine(detail.Description);
                Console.WriteLine(trigger.Key.Name);
                Console.WriteLine(trigger.Key.Group);
                Console.WriteLine(trigger.GetType().Name);
                Console.WriteLine(scheduler.GetTriggerState(trigger.Key));
                DateTimeOffset? nextFireTime = trigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc();
                if (nextFireTime.HasValue)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(nextFireTime.Value.LocalDateTime.ToString());
                }

                DateTimeOffset? previousFireTime = trigger.GetPreviousFireTimeUtc();
                if (previousFireTime.HasValue)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(previousFireTime.Value.LocalDateTime.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

**I've used the code found [here](https://github.com/adometry/QuartzNetManager/blob/master/ClickForensics.Quartz.Manager/QuartzScheduler.cs).**

**UPDATE**:

If someone is interested a sample code can be downloaded from my GitHub [repository](https://github.com/Leftyx/QuartzNetXmlJobs).

Someone asked how to get a list of job completed.
I don't think there's an easy way for that.
The only option which comes to mind is using a job (or trigger) listener.

I've uploaded a [sample](https://github.com/Leftyx/QuartzNetWithJobListener) on github where my main program can receive events of completed jobs.

Comment: The 2nd block of code was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: In that example, what is "sched" and where does it come from?

Comment: It doesn't work in case the jobs and triggers are loaded from the .config file. Any solution?

Comment: @Rwiti: It does work. You can try it yourself [repo](https://github.com/Leftyx/QuartzNetXmlJobs). Cheers.

Comment: @LeftyX How would you get a list of jobs that have already completed?

Comment: @Howiecamp: I guess you have to use listeners for that. Check my [repository](https://github.com/Leftyx/QuartzNetWithJobListener) on GitHub.

Comment: @leftyx Now I understand that Quartz keeps no history of its own and that if I do want to track ongoing history I can do so myself within the listeners. I just was trying to find out if Quartz kept it natively.

Comment: @Howiecamp: I don't think it can but I must say I haven't followed the evolution of the framework as I switched to a different one.

Comment: @leftyx - Actually now I am certain (based on research and your answer) that preserving job history is not an automatic function of Quartz.  So I definitely agree that you can do it yourself and the listener is the best place.

Comment: @LeftyX In the above GetAllJobs code how would you access the jobdata for each of the jobs (normally available in the execution context)?

Comment: @Matt: If I understand your question, when you have an `IJobDetail` you have access to all the info related to a job.

Comment: @LeftyX - As part of reporting on scheduled+currently running jobs (like `GetAllJobs`) I wanted to include `JobDataMap` info for the jobs. I know (per your comment) that you need a `JobDetail` to get the `JobDataMap`, and in a job's `Execute()` method or a listener you can grab the `JobDetail` from the `JobExecutionContext` as follows: `JobDataMap dataMap = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap;` Where I'm not clear is how/if I can get this info as part of the 'GetAllJobs' listing, because I don't have access to the `JobExecutionContext`. I feel like I *should* be able to get it since it does exist...

Comment: @Matt: Info for the `JobDataMap` can be found in [IJobDetail](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz/IJobDetail.cs). In the function above at some point you can find `var detail = scheduler.GetJobDetail(jobKey);`. `detail` now references an object of type `IJobDetail` so you should be able to do `JobDataMap dataMap = detail.JobDataMap;`

Comment: @LeftyX Perfect...  It was right there in front of me and I didn't see it.  Thanks a lot - it works like a charm.

Comment: @Matt: Glad I've helped. Cheers.

Comment: @LukeHutton: Thanks. Fixed. Cheers.

Comment: Don't use var groupMatcher = GroupMatcher<JobKey>.GroupContains(group); 
If one groupname contains the other you will get faulty data. e.g. If one group is named 'orders' and the other 'preorders' you will have match on both in one case.

Answer (score 10):

Since Quartz.NET version 2.2.1 you can make use of `GroupMatcher<>.AnyGroup()`, here implemented as an extension method to `IScheduler`:

```
public static List<IJobDetail> GetJobs(this IScheduler scheduler)
{
    List<IJobDetail> jobs = new List<IJobDetail>();

    foreach (JobKey jobKey in scheduler.GetJobKeys(GroupMatcher<JobKey>.AnyGroup()))
    {
        jobs.Add(scheduler.GetJobDetail(jobKey));
    }

    return jobs;
}
```

This will get you a list of `IJobDetail`s for every scheduled job.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get the Repeat Interval, Repeat Count etc cast the ITrigger to ISimpleTrigger

```
private void LogInfo(IScheduler scheduler) 
{
    log.Info(string.Format("\n\n{0}\n", Scheduler.GetMetaData().GetSummary()));

    var jobGroups = scheduler.GetJobGroupNames();
    var builder = new StringBuilder().AppendLine().AppendLine();

    foreach (var group in jobGroups)
    {
        var groupMatcher = GroupMatcher<JobKey>.GroupContains(group);
        var jobKeys = scheduler.GetJobKeys(groupMatcher);

        foreach (var jobKey in jobKeys)
        {
            var detail = scheduler.GetJobDetail(jobKey);
            var triggers = scheduler.GetTriggersOfJob(jobKey);

            foreach (ITrigger trigger in triggers)
            {
                builder.AppendLine(string.Format("Job: {0}", jobKey.Name));
                builder.AppendLine(string.Format("Description: {0}", detail.Description));
                var nextFireTime = trigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc();
                if (nextFireTime.HasValue)
                {
                    builder.AppendLine(string.Format("Next fires: {0}", nextFireTime.Value.LocalDateTime));
                }
                var previousFireTime = trigger.GetPreviousFireTimeUtc();
                if (previousFireTime.HasValue)
                {
                    builder.AppendLine(string.Format("Previously fired: {0}", previousFireTime.Value.LocalDateTime));
                }
                var simpleTrigger = trigger as ISimpleTrigger;
                if (simpleTrigger != null)
                {
                    builder.AppendLine(string.Format("Repeat Interval: {0}", simpleTrigger.RepeatInterval));
                }
                builder.AppendLine();
            }
        }
    }

    builder.AppendLine().AppendLine();
    log.Info(builder.ToString); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For **Quartz.NET version 3.0** you can use

this will show you all running jobs and triggers in quartz.net 3.x

```
using Quartz;
using Quartz.Impl;
using Quartz.Impl.Matchers;

    class Program
    {
            var allTriggerKeys = scheduler.GetTriggerKeys(GroupMatcher<TriggerKey>.AnyGroup());
            foreach (var triggerKey in allTriggerKeys.Result)
            {
             var triggerdetails =   scheduler.GetTrigger(triggerKey);
             var Jobdetails = scheduler.GetJobDetail(triggerdetails.Result.JobKey);

                Console.WriteLine("IsCompleted -" + triggerdetails.IsCompleted + " |  TriggerKey  - " + triggerdetails.Result.Key.Name + " Job key -" + triggerdetails.Result.JobKey.Name);

            }
}
```

**I've used the code found** [here](http://programmingkeys.blogspot.com/2018/01/get-all-jobs-and-triggers-details-in.html).