# getNextFireTime of my existing job

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I tried Quartz.com documentation & googled for couple for hours...but could not find single good article on how to get Next Job (which is supposr to fire in future).

I am using CronTrigger Expression to Schedule jobs, using VB.net (winforms). jobs works  fine...however I would like my users to see when will it FIRE next. I am storing CronExpression in my database, Can I use that Expression to show **next Fire Date/Time** to my end users? or if there is any other way possible please advise (with a simple samply).

Thanks

Edit

Following Code Returns next job will fire after 12 minutes instead of 20 minute

```
    Dim exp As CronExpression = New CronExpression("0 0/20 * * * ?")
    Dim nextFire As String = exp.GetNextValidTimeAfter(DateTime.Now)
    MsgBox(nextFire)
```

Comment: Your cronExpression should fire at 00:00 then 00:20 , then 00:40 etc. So if you start it at 00:01 it will run 19 minutes later and if you start 00:19, it will run 1 minute later. (See also http://www.cronmaker.com/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a new JobKey

```
JobKey jobKey = new JobKey(jobName, groupName);
```

and use the key to fetch the job detail:

```
var detail = scheduler.GetJobDetail(jobKey);
```

this is a simple function which does what you're looking for:

```
    private DateTime getNextFireTimeForJob(IScheduler scheduler, string jobName, string groupName = "")
    {
        JobKey jobKey = new JobKey(jobName, groupName);
        DateTime nextFireTime = DateTime.MinValue;

        bool isJobExisting = Scheduler.CheckExists(jobKey);
        if (isJobExisting)
        {
            var detail = scheduler.GetJobDetail(jobKey);
            var triggers = scheduler.GetTriggersOfJob(jobKey);

            if (triggers.Count > 0)
            {
                var nextFireTimeUtc = triggers[0].GetNextFireTimeUtc();
                nextFireTime = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(nextFireTimeUtc.Value.DateTime);
            }
        }

        return (nextFireTime);
    }
```

It works only if you have one trigger per job.
If there's more than one trigger in your job you can loop through them:

```
foreach (ITrigger trigger in triggers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(jobKey.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(detail.Description);
    Console.WriteLine(trigger.Key.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(trigger.Key.Group);
    Console.WriteLine(trigger.GetType().Name);
    Console.WriteLine(scheduler.GetTriggerState(trigger.Key));
    DateTimeOffset? nextFireTime = trigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc();
    if (nextFireTime.HasValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(nextFireTime.Value.DateTime).ToString());
    }
}
```

or using Linq (`System.Linq`) :

```
 var myTrigger = triggers.Where(f => f.Key.Name == "[trigger name]").SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: in my api i see "JobKey" as a Member of Class TriggerWrapper, Hence I cant make a new instance of JobKey. I am using quartz.net latest version.

Comment: Is there a way to find all occurences within a datetime range?

Answer (score 4):

If you already know the cronExpression then you can call GetNextValidTimeAfter , eg

```
CronExpression exp = new CronExpression("0 0 0/1 1/1 * ? *");
var nextFire = exp.GetNextValidTimeAfter(DateTime.Now);
Console.WriteLine(nextFire);
```

and if you want more fire times, then

```
for(int i=0 ; i< 9; i++)
{
    if (nextFire.HasValue)
    {
        nextFire = exp.GetNextValidTimeAfter(nextFire.Value);        
        Console.WriteLine(nextFire);
     }
}
```

If you are looking for a more general way of showing next fire times for existing jobs,  then check out the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489450/get-all-jobs-in-quartz-net-2-0) question which works even if you aren't using cron expressions. This is for Quartz Version 2

The Quartz Version 1 way of getting job and trigger information is something like the method below.

```
 public void GetListOfJobs(IScheduler scheduler)
 {
    var query =
        (from groupName in scheduler.JobGroupNames
         from jobName in scheduler.GetJobNames(groupName)
         let triggers = scheduler.GetTriggersOfJob(jobName, groupName)
         select new 
            { 
                groupName, 
                jobName, 
                triggerInfo = (from trigger in triggers select trigger) 
            }
        );

   foreach (var r in query)
   {
       if (r.triggerInfo.Count() == 0)
       {
           var details = String.Format("No triggers found for : Group {0}  Job {1}", r.groupName, r.jobName);
           Console.WriteLine(details);                   
       }

       foreach (var t in r.triggerInfo)
       {
           var details = String.Format("{0,-50} {9} Next Due {1,30:r} Last Run {2,30:r}  Group {3,-30}, Trigger {4,-50} {5,-50} Scheduled from {6:r} Until {7,30:r} {8,30:r} ",
               t.JobName,
               t.GetNextFireTimeUtc().ToLocalTime(), 
               t.GetPreviousFireTimeUtc().ToLocalTime(),
               t.JobGroup, 
               t.Name, 
               t.Description,
               t.StartTimeUtc.ToLocalTime(), 
               t.EndTimeUtc.ToLocalTime(), 
               t.FinalFireTimeUtc.ToLocalTime(),
               ((t.GetNextFireTimeUtc() > DateTime.UtcNow) ? "Active  " : "InActive")
               );

           Console.WriteLine(details);

       }
   }
```

}

Comment: i am not using Quartz.net 2.0, I tried to use 2.0 with my project and all of my code failed to compiled:(

Comment: There was quite a few api changes going from V1 to V2, but they are tedious but fairly straightforward. I think the  CronExpression.GetNextValidTimeAfter method is the same, but I have included a sample showing how to retrieve existing jobs and triggers under version 1.

Comment: Thanks, do you know where can i find examples for creating jobs with v2? Official website has no exsmples for new version.

Comment: There is an Examples project in the source which you can download from https://github.com/quartznet/ or for a simple example see http://jvilalta.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/scheduling-jobs-programmatically-in_09.html  or just google for JobBuilder.Create  Don't forget to check out the migration guide http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/migration_guide.html

Answer (score 0):

I had problem where i am getting next execution time even for the date which are past the end time.
Following is my implementation which eventually returning the correct result in Quartz 3.0.4

```
internal static DateTime? GetNextFireTimeForJob(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            JobKey jobKey = context.JobDetail.Key;
            DateTime? nextFireTime = null;

            var isJobExisting = MyQuartzScheduler.CheckExists(jobKey);
            if (isJobExisting.Result)
            {
                var triggers = MyQuartzScheduler.GetTriggersOfJob(jobKey);

                if (triggers.Result.Count > 0)
                {
                    var nextFireTimeUtc =  triggers.Result.First().GetNextFireTimeUtc();
                    if (nextFireTimeUtc.HasValue)
                    {
                        nextFireTime = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(nextFireTimeUtc.Value.DateTime);
                    }
                }
            }

            return nextFireTime;
        }
```