# Quartz get jobs that are running

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, jobs

is there a way to get the identities of the running Jobs from any class in C#?
I'm using `Quartz.net` for creating jobs.

let's say i defined a job like:

```
IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<Mailer>()
            .WithIdentity("MailJob", "group1")
            .UsingJobData("t2", "f2")
            .Build();
```

My idea is to create an overview of all running jobs, for that i want to get the name of each Job, e.g here `MailJob` to list it up in a table.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried to write a method like the following, but don't know how to get the right instance of the jobs from another class:

public string getRunningJobs()
        {
            string running_jobs = "";
            ISchedulerFactory scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            IScheduler sched = scheduler.GetScheduler();

            var executingJobs = sched.GetCurrentlyExecutingJobs();
            foreach (var job in executingJobs)
            {
                running_jobs += job.JobDetail.Key;
            }

            return running_jobs;
        }

Comment: resolved with 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489450/get-all-jobs-in-quartz-net-2-0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all jobs in Quartz.NET 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489450/get-all-jobs-in-quartz-net-2-0)