# Get all jobs in Quartz.NET 3.0

Tags: c#, quartz

I have jobs that are running correctly, but I need to list these from another application. I'm using Quartz version 3.0.7

I have used the following code:

```
        var collJobGroups = await pScheduler.GetJobGroupNames();
```

but it does not return anything.
this one either:

```
        StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings);
        IScheduler scheduler = await factory.GetScheduler();
        await scheduler.Start();

        IReadOnlyCollection<string> jgn = await scheduler.GetJobGroupNames(new System.Threading.CancellationToken());
```

Comment: **but I need to list these from another application**, i dont think thats possible. Isn't Quartz register the jobs in memory?

Comment: I am registering from an asp.net MVC app, and it does not list the jobs.

Comment: oh its on web application? then you can create an endpoint to allow another application queries to your app. i believe you can fetch the current registered jobs using the approach explained on [tGet all jobs in Quartz.NET 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12492279/4648586). if the api isnt changed that is.

Comment: Bagus Tesa , if precisely there I started and nothing returns. and my job runs correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both applications have access to the same database then I recommend that you look at the ADO.NET Job Store instead of RAMJobStore. When you use a database as a Job Store then you can have Scheduler running in one application, and you can read job information through another application.
The only problem is that you need to have jobs implemented in a separate class library because you need to have access to classes to create JobDetails.

Comment: msestak, Apparently you mean hangfire, but I use Quartz.NET 3.0. Can you access this database?

Comment: Quartz.NET 3 can also be configured to use database like HangFire. Check http://programmingkeys.blogspot.com/2018/02/quartznet-302-configure-adojobstore.html . So if two apps share same configuration, second app can read jobs and triggers.